# Alguma ajuda no exercicio de funcao (python)

Tags: python

O exercicio fala o seguinte :

**"Escreva uma função que recebe um inteiro positivo m e devolve 1 se m é primo, 0 em caso contrário."**

Minha tentativa :

edit: Então , realizada as modificações o programa ainda não está devolvendo os valores de 1 ou 0 ( caso o numero seja impar ou par).

```
m = int(input("Digite um numero inteiro:"))    

def recebe_m(m):

  n_divisores = 0
  i = 1

  while(i <= m):        
      if(m%i==0):           
          n_divisores = n_divisores + 1

  i = i+1

  if(n_divisores==2):
      return(1)
 else:
      return(0)

  print(recebe_m(m))
```

obs : eu optei por deixar o i <= m , espero que nao tenha problema.

Eu estou estou recebendo o seguinte erro do python :

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'i' referenced before assignment

Comment: Seu código está com a indentação toda errada. Você está tentando executar o código exatamente assim ou só foi falha na formatação do mesmo ao postá-lo aqui?

Comment: Acho que estou falhando em postar o código aqui Anderson, não sei direito como faz.

Comment: E como testou? Tem como postar o código no [Repl.it](https://repl.it)? Eu testei aqui com as indetações corretas e retornou 0 e 1 como esperado.

Comment: Eu testei e nao deu certo. O que você fez ? Copiou o códio e colocou no Repl.it ?

Comment: Sim, ajustando todas as indentações incorretas.

Comment: Eu consegui agora. Eu estava copiando do meu próprio texto , quando eu copiei do seu deu certo. O que será que errei ? Somente a identação ?       edit: acho que descobri o que eu errei.O i = i +1 está fora do if.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa declarar a variável `i` dentro da função `recebe_m`. O mesmo problema irá ocorrer com a variável `n_divisores`, declare a mesma dentro da função.

```
m = int(input("Digite um numero inteiro:"))    
def recebe_m(m):
     n_divisores = 0
     i = 1
     while(i <= m/2):        
        if(m%i==0):           
           n_divisores = n_divisores + 1

        i = i+1

    if(n_divisores==1):
        return(1)
    else:
        return(0)
print(recebe_m(m))
```

Além disso, como o amigo da outra resposta disse, você está tentando dividir por 0 na primeira iteração do seu loop while, corrija isso e inicialize `i` com 1.

O problema do seu código é com escopo de variáveis. Em python caso você declare uma variável num escopo mais interno, e a mesma variável exista num escopo global, a variável do escopo mais interna será a utilizada pelo python para fazer os cálculos.

No seu código você tenta declarar e incrementar uma variável na mesma linha num caso que a variável `i` não existe no escopo interno ainda, isso que ocasiona o erro. O mesmo vale para `n_divisores`.

Para entender melhor:

```
x = 10
def func():
    x = 5
    print(x)
func() # printa 5
print(x) # printa 10, x com valor 5 morreu.
```

Edit: Assim como o @Anderson disse, não é necessário checar todos os números e sim apenas a metade deles `(i <=m/2)`

Comment: Acho que entendi algumas das alterações , mas o programa ainda não está devolvendo os valores 1 ou 0. Isso eu ainda nao entendi o porque .Eu nao entendi tame por que (n_divisores==1) , tambem. (isso seria porque voce dividiu o m por 2 ?)

Comment: @user158657 eu mudei alguma coisa no codigo e ta dando erro pra mim, também vou dar uma olhada aqui. E sim, é porque eu dividi m por 2, dai o criterio pra ser primo é ele ser divisivel apenas por 1 (ter apenas um divisor). No meu caso era erro de identação, veja funcionando no [replit](https://repl.it/Iv9w/1)

Comment: @user158657 se tiver conseguido resolver seu problema com a ajuda de alguma das respostas, marque a que mais ajudou como "respondida" pra sinalizar que sua duvida foi sanada.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo oq pude perceber, vc teria a intenção um [int]%0 no primeiro caso? Não se divide por zero haha (a n ser q queira abrir um buraco negro rsrs)

Você precisa declarar a variável n_divisores dentro do def

o codigo fica:

```
m = int(input("Numero: "))
def recebe_m(m):
    cont=0
    for x in range(1,m+1):        
        if(m%x==0):
            cont+=1    
    if(cont==2):
        return(1)
    else:
        return (0)

print(recebe_m(m))
```

Answer (score 0):

Procurei deixar a função o mais simples possível

Você não precisa contabilizar os divisores, se existir qualquer divisor entre 1 e a metade dele mesmo, você já pode definir que o número não é primo.

A função as seguir percorre todos os números de `2 até m/2`, e se achar algum divisor retorna **0**, se ele terminar o loop sem encontrar nenhum ele retorna **1**

```
m = int(input("Digite um numero inteiro:"))

def recebe_m(m):
  for i in range(2, int(m/2)):
    if m%i==0:           
      return(0)

  return(1)

print(recebe_m(m))
```

Comment: "Não de o peixe, ensine a pescar"

Comment: Coloquei a explicação para ele entender o código

Comment: E o maior divisor possível de um número é a metade dele, então não há porquê fazer o `range` até `m-1`, pode ser apenas até `int(m/2)`.